# Proof of Thm: For a linear map $f:V\to W$ with $X\subset V$, $Y\subset W$ with $X\cap f^{-1}[Y]=\{0\}$, we have a injective restriction $f|_X$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading a chapter in my Linear Algebra book about nilpotent endomorphisms and it contains the following theorem: Let $f:V\to W$ be linear map and $X\subset V$, $Y\subset W$ such that $X\cap f^{-1}[Y]=\{0\}$. Then $f$ restricted to $X$ is injective and $f[X]\cap Y=\{0\}$. The first rule of the proof is: The function $f|_X$ satisfies $\ker(f|_X)=X\cap\ker(f)\subset X\cap f^{-1}[Y]=\{0\}$. However I have no clue whatsoever why this inclusion holds. May be there is something I'm missing and I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in X \cap\ker(f)$. Assume that $x \ne 0$. Then $x \notin f^{-1}(Y)$ since $X \cap f^{-1}(Y) = \{ 0 \}$. Hence $f(x) \notin Y$ and therefore $f(x) \ne 0$. Thus $x \notin\ker(f)$, a contradiction.

Edited: Although probably $X, Y$ are assumed to be linear subspaces of $V, W$, the proof works for **arbitrary** subsets $X, Y$. The key is that $f(x) \notin Y$ implies $f(x) \ne 0$. This follows from $X \cap f^{-1}(Y) = \{ 0 \}$: We have $0 \in f^{-1}(Y)$ and therefore $0 = f(0) \in Y$.

Answer (score 1):

$X\cap f^{-1}[Y]=\{0_V\}\implies 0_V\in f^{-1}[Y]\implies f(0_V)=0_W\in Y$

Since $0_W$ belongs to $Y$, the entire null-space of $f,\ker(f)\subseteq f^{-1}[Y]$.$$\therefore X\cap\ker(f)\subseteq X\cap f^{-1}[Y]$$Since $X\cap f^{-1}[Y]$ contains only $0_V$, no other element of $\ker(f)$ is contained in $X.$

$$\therefore\ker(f\Big|_X)=\{0_V\}$$

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is $\ker(f)=f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and $f^{-1}[\{0\}]\subseteq f^{-1}[Y]$. More generally, if $S$ and $T$ are subsets of $W$, then $S\subseteq T$ implies $f^{-1}[S]\subseteq f^{-1}[T]$; indeed, if $v\in f^{-1}[S]$, then $f(v)\in S$, so $f(v)\in T$, hence $v\in f^{-1}[T]$.

Therefore
$$
X\cap\ker(f)=X\cap f^{-1}[\{0\}]\subseteq X\cap f^{-1}[Y]
$$
The fact that $\ker(f|_X)=X\cap\ker(f)$ follows immediately from the definition of kernel and of restriction map.

Why is $f[X]\cap Y=\{0\}$? Well, if $v\in X$, then $f(v)\in Y$ implies $v\in f^{-1}[Y]$; therefore $v\in X\cap f^{-1}[Y]$ and therefore $v=0$, so $f(v)=0$.